# What does inlined mean?

Tags: scala, inline

This is a proposal to introduce syntax for classes in Scala that can get completely inlined, so operations on these classes have zero overhead compared to external methods.

In above sentence, does usage of the word "inlined" refer to the JVM inlining? JVM inlining is where for example if a function always evaluates to a same result, then the value is stamped for that function invocation.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "JVM inlining?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inlining refers to situation where the compiler inserts the complete body of the function in every place that the function is called rather than generating code to call the function.

More information [here](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion).